# problem whith MSMQ while changing OS from xp to win7

Tags: msmq

In ower system we have two machines which connected by MSMSQ. one machine contains two static ip addresses (each ip belongs to other lan) and the second one using one ip address. We have a proccedure which change the ip address of the machine with one ip address to ip belongs to the lan of one of the ip address of the machine contains two ip address. the problem is that each time after changing the ip MSMQ connect after 15 minutes. On xp it was immidate.
What can couse this?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 7 situation sounds 'normal'. MSMQ relies on TCP/IP name resolution. If you change the IP address of a PC, other machines don't immediately know about it until cached information is replaced with new.
The Windows XP situation implies that the way MSMQ uses the cached information, or the way the PC caches information, was tweaked.

- MSMQ and cached IP addresses

http://geekswithblogs.net/Plumbersmate/archive/2011/08/19/msmq-and-cached-ip-addresses.aspx

You will need the Wayback Machine for the KB article I reference

https://web.archive.org/web/20100212070948/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833512